# How a column change its value after a determined time in Sql Server 2005

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2005

I have a table (tblMessage) with columns (id, title, contents, publishingDateTime, status). The publishingDateTime column is the Date in which the message will publish. I want to change the value of column (status) automatically from (pending to published - OR - from false to true) when it is reached to its publishingDateTime.

How it is possible in Sql Server 2005?

Comment: Do you mean you need to perform this update on a timed basis?

Comment: @Kelley... Yes of course

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Probably the easiest way is to not change the value at all.  Instead, use a calculated column, with logic such as:

```
status as (case when publishingDateTime > getdate() then 'Published' else 'Pending' end)
```

This goes in the `create table` statement and is explained [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174979%28v=sql.90%29.aspx).

You can also do something similar by creating a view and doing all access to the table through a view (often a good idea anyway).

As an example, I the create table statement would look like:

```
create table xxx (
    -- all your columns go here
    status as (case when publishingDateTime > getdate() then 'Published' else 'Pending' end)
)
```

For a view, you would do something like:

```
create view vw_SMS as
    select sms.*, 
           (case when publishingDateTime > getdate() then 'Published' else 'Pending'
            end) as status
    from SMS
```

It is actually better practice not to use the `*` in the view, but to list out all the columns.

Comment: +1 Personally, I like the idea of a view with the extra column.

Comment: Yep, there should be no need to constantly modify the value in the table when you can always determine what it should be at runtime. I would probably opt for the view option before the computed column unless the column is going to be referenced in a majority of queries (in which case I would try to make sure it is deterministic and then persist and possibly index it).

Comment: @Gordon Linoff......Here is my table creation script, where i can place the above code?    

`CREATE TABLE [dbo].[SMS](
 [id] [int] NOT NULL,
 [message] [nvarchar](50) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL,
 [publishingDateTime] [datetime] NULL,
 [status] [nvarchar](50) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_SMS] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
 [id] ASC
)WITH (IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]`

Comment: @Gordon Linoff... May the code you created will work for all the time without creating jobs, or schedule?

Comment: @Gordon Linoff... the code i tried but it mentioned a message....**Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 5
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'as'.**

Comment: @Gordon Linoff   Very Very Special man...well done...Good Job.... Appreciative...Finally it works as i wanted.....thanks

Comment: @Gordon Linoff ..... Can you help me with this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14849546/getting-the-exact-edited-data-from-sql-server/14849941#14849941

Answer (score 0):

Well normally your application should do this imho,

but if you just want to let sql server something like this

```
UPDATE tblMessage
SET status = 0
WHERE publishingDateTime <= GETDATE()
```

and then create a agent job that runs this in a sheduled time.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a Transact-SQL job that will execute a Stored Procedure that will update your status column based on the publish date.

See documentation here:

- [Creating jobs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186273%28v=sql.90%29.aspx)
- [Transact-SQL jobs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187910%28v=sql.90%29.aspx)